# Swift Popovers iOS 7 dismissViewController Not Working

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason it seems that the following code doesn't work for popovers in iOS 7 when using Swift:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

There are no errors but the popover doesn't dismiss.  It works fine in iOS 8.  Do I need to do something different in iOS 7?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, popovers were extensively reworked in iOS8 to be fully fledged view controllers.

To dismiss in iOS7 you need to call `dismissPopoverAnimated:` on the `UIPopoverController` instance. You can do this from the content controller by passing a reference to the owning UIPopoverController , to the content view controller.

like...

```
class MyViewController:UIViewController {

var parentPopover:UIPopoverController?


func dismissPopover() {

parentPopover?.dismissPopoverAnimated(true)

}
```

and then when setting up...

```
func popoverThatThing() {

let mvc = MyViewController()
let popover = UIPopoverViewController(contentViewController:mvc)
mvc.parentPopover = popover

popover.presentFromWhatever...


}
```

or even easier, don't support iOS7

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that your send idea is easier!